# Solving $z^3=1+i \sqrt3$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

How can I solve the complex equation $$z^3=1+i \sqrt3$$

Splitting $z$ into $z=a+bi$ gives me the mess

$$a^3+3a^2b^2i-3ab^2-b^3i-i \sqrt3-1=0$$

where I dont know how to continue. I have never really worked with complex numbers, so I am not familiar with the "tricks" or steps that have to be done.

Comment: maybe read your friendly text book first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You approach this using the fact that$$1+i\sqrt3=2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)\right)$$and using de Moivre's formula.

Comment: Thanks. So what I get is

$a=2^{\frac{1}{3}}\cos({\pi \over 9}), b=2^{\frac{1}{3}} \sin({\frac{\pi}{9}})$?

Comment: That's one of three solutions, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$a^3-3ab^2-1=0$$ and $$3a^2b^2-b^3-\sqrt{3}=0$$ must hold. So we obtain $$b=3\,{\frac {a \left( {a}^{4}-\sqrt {3}-a \right) }{{a}^{3}-1}}$$ and then you can compute $$a$$.

Comment: This is true, but it's not so easy to solve.

Comment: Should i post the solution for you?

Comment: But how do you solve it easily?

Answer (score 3):

For products of complex numbers it's often easiest to use the polar form, $z = r e^{i \phi}$, which yields $z^3 = r^3 e^{3 i \phi}$. Converting the right-hand side of the equation to this form yields $1 + i \sqrt{3} = 2 e^{i \frac{\pi}{3}}$ (cf. the hint of José Carlos Santos). Now you compare both sides to obtain two easily solvable equations for $r$ and $\phi$.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, by using the exponential form (instead of the cartesian one)
$$1+i \sqrt3=2\exp(i\pi/3),$$
it is easier to solve the equation $z^n=1+i \sqrt3$ where $n$ is a positive integer.  There are $n$ distinct solutions given by
$$z_k=2^{1/n}\exp\left(i\frac{\pi/3+2k\pi}{n}\right)\quad \text{for $k=0,1,2,\dots,n-1$}.$$
As a reference take a look at [$n$-roots of a complex  number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#nth_roots).